How can a quad be triangulated consistently in 3D?
I'm making a building game and the terrain and modelling system are based on cubes made out of 8 corners each. Players can manipulate the corners to make other shapes.
When you take a quad (ABCD), triangulate it (ABC - ACD), and appends them to a mesh, you have a slice between both triangles (obviously). Now, here is problem: changing the opposite corner of a block gives a different result.

The desired result is the triangulation of the first two blocks in the image when manipulating his opposite vertices.
Flipping the diagonal cut when the quad is convex is probably the best solution for me, but I am not good at math and could not think of an algorithm to prove if a face is convex.
For disclosure, this is a Godot 4 game using ArrayMesh.

Do you just need to check whether your current diagonal is a valley fold (concave / acute angle between the faces) or a mountain fold (convex / obtuse angle between the faces)? If so, we have existing Q&A covering that.

@DMGregory this worked perfectly! Thanks :D

By following this solution suggested by DMGregory on his comment, I was able to detect convex faces and invert the quad diagonal, and now the triangulation is consistent on both sides of the cube.

